# In svelte, I need to set the focus on an input element, but I get the error 'input.focus is not a function'

Tags: input, components, focus, svelte

```
<script >
let inx1 = "null";
let input ="";

function handleClick() {input.focus();  }
$: inx1 && handleClick();
</script>

<textarea  style="clear: both;">{inx1}</textarea> 
<br/>
<input  bind:this={input} placeholder="SET"/> 
<button on:click={handleClick}>  Focus input</button>
```

If I open the page, I get the error:

input.focus is not a function

If I remove this code: '
&& handleClick()
it works and I can get the focus on the input element when I click the button

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

The `input` will not be set until the component is mounted. I also would not recommend setting the variable to some completely different type in the mean time, just let it stay `undefined` and check before interacting with it:

```js
let input;

$: if (input && inx1) handleClick();
```

Once the `input` is assigned the statement will be reevaluated which should automatically focus the input if `inx1` is truthy. Of course it will also retrigger on any change to `inx1`, not sure if that is really intended.

If the truthiness does not matter, you can just use a block and not include the value in the `if` condition:

```js
$: { inx1; if (input) handleClick(); }
```

---

If you just want to focus the input once on mount, you can also use an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-action):

```html
<script>
  const focus = node => node.focus();
</script>
<input use:focus />
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!! 

And if my variable inx1 is set from within a component binding like this: 

<List1 bind:selex= {inx1} /> 

I want the focus happen when inx1 change inside the component ;

the value inside a text component like this :
<textarea bind:value={inx1} ></textarea> 
is updated, but the focus won't occur

Comment: If you want to focus on any change, not just truthy values, do not include it in the `if` (added example for that). If the value comes from a component you have to pass it through props and have to use `bind:...` at every level, otherwise the value will not be passed back up.